# What is this boolean law?

Tags: c, boolean

A friend of mine has shown sometime ago the name of the below boolean technique/law but I forget that name unfortunately. Does someone know what it's called?

example in C language:

```
!(a || b)
```

It's a short to:

```
!a && !b
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `!a && !b`?

Comment: yes, edited. I'm sorry.

Comment: In this case, the first is longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a law - in fact it's quite wrong!

You want `!a && !b`. Then its one of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: yes, it was what I wanted. edited. I'm sorry.